# .Find() only visible elements

Tags: javascript

I have a method that gets all focusable elements on the UI

```
this.GetFocusItems = function (source) {
        var container = $(source);
        return container.find("input,select,textarea,button,object,[tabindex],a");
    };
```

**But I don't want to get input elements that are hidden**

So the above code also get the below element defined as

```
@Html.Hidden("ProductNames", String.Join(",$,", allProducts))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`:visible` selector.](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

```
container
    .find("input,select,textarea,button,object,[tabindex],a")
    .filter(":visible");
```